# How to attach claims in the token when logging in to a hosted Blazor Wasm app?

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-client-side

I've created a hosted Blazor Wasm with identity. I've create a user. I also added a couple of claims.

```cs
var adminClaims = new List<Claim>
{
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, RoleEnums.Admin),
   new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.TenantUrl, viewModel.InstitutionUrl)
};
await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(userCreateresult.User, adminClaims);
```

After the above code is run, I can verify that 2 claims have been added to the **AspNetUserClaims** table.

However, when I run the application the below code is not working, i.e. the portion of the HTML is not displaying.

```xml
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
   <Authorized>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
          <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
             <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
          </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
          <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
              <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
          </NavLink>
      </li>
   </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I tried to add as it's suggested in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#name-and-role-claim-with-api-authorization), but it didn't work.

When looking at the code in the `/Server/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml.cs` where user's being logged in, I don't see where the token is being created.

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
   // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
   var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
       _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
       return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
   }

   //more code here...
}
```

What to do so that, when user logs in, the token sent contains all his/her claims.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution from [Felipe Gavilan's course](https://www.udemy.com/course/programming-in-blazor-aspnet-core/learn/lecture/18577850#overview) on Udemy.

1. Create this class that implements **IProfileService**

   ```cs
   public class IdentityProfileService : IProfileService
   {
       private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory;
       private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

       public IdentityProfileService(
           IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
           UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
       {
           this.claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
           this.userManager = userManager;
       }
       public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
       {
           var userId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
           var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
           var claimsPrincipal = await claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
           var claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();

           var claimsFromDb = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
           var mappedClaims = new List<Claim>();
           foreach (var claim in claimsFromDb)
           {
               if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                   mappedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, claim.Value));
               else
                   mappedClaims.Add(claim);
           }

           claims.AddRange(mappedClaims);
           context.IssuedClaims = claims;
       }

       public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
       {
           var userId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
           var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
           context.IsActive = user != null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then register the service

   ```cs
   services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>(); //adding this line.
   ```

That's all. Now I'm getting claims embedded in the JWT token.